# helping with an excell folmula to calculate the best pokemon types to have on your journey

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2016

we are making a custom pokedex with all our custom pokemon and we made somethin in excell like this:

[image: dex_info]

this table has the name Dex_Info

then we added this table for reference

[image]

this table has the name Type_Counters

now we wanted to make a formula that calculates what are the best types to put into your team, that do the most damage to enemy Pokémon's statistically speaking based on their types and the enemy types.

I tried a formula like this:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((Dex_Info[Type 1]=[Type])*INDEX(Type_Counters[[Normal]:[Fairy]], MATCH(Dex_Info[Type 2], Type_Counters[Type], 0), MATCH([Type], Type_Counters[Type], 0)))
```

I do the formula on this table:

[image]

but so far I only get #name? as feedback.

does anybody know how to fixe this?
and if there are better ways to do this, please let me know!

P.S. I'm using excel 2016

thanks in advance!

Comment: `#NAME` means exactly that: you are not using a name properly: it can be a function name or a named range name, like your second match `MATCH([Type]` i think the table name is missing???

Comment: do i need to add tabvle name if i am working in the table itself?

Comment: i did change it to Best_types[Type] on bo9th occassion, but i keep getting the error

Comment: Check [Using structured references with Excel tables](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/using-structured-references-with-excel-tables-f5ed2452-2337-4f71-bed3-c8ae6d2b276e)

Comment: Thanks! i did check en [Type] works, if i do Best_types[Type] excell automatically renames it to [Type]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is in Dutch, but your formulas are in English. Maybe you need to use the Dutch language formulas, I believe SOMPRODUCT, INDEX, VERGLIJKEN

Comment: that was indeed the case!!